# Minesweeper game

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm

do you know the minesweeper game of windows . well , the following problem is the same , you will input m and n ...

```
0 < n,m <= 100
n : colons , m : rows
```

> input :

```
4 4
*...
....
.*..
....
```

> output :

```
*100
2210
1*10
1110
```

and , that is my code .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char ms[100][101] ;
int m , n;
void input(){
    for(int r = 0 ; r < m ; r++)
        for(int c = 0 ; c <= n ; c++){
            scanf("%c",&ms[r][c]);
            if('.' == ms[r][c])
                ms[r][c] += 2 ;
        }
}
void calc(int m , int n){
    for(int r = m ; r <= (m+2) ; r++)
        for(int c = n ; c <= (n+2) ; c++)
            if(r >= 0 && c >= 0 && ms[r][c] != '*')
                ms[r][c] += 1 ;

}
void solve(){
    for(int r = 0 ; r < m ; r++)
        for(int c = 0 ; c < n ; c++)
            if( '*' == ms[r][c])
                calc(r-1 , c-1);
}
void output(){
    for(int r = 0 ; r < m ; r++)
        for(int c = 0 ; c <= n ; c++)
            printf("%c ", ms[r][c]);
}
int main()
{

    scanf("%d%d" , &m , &n);
    input();
    solve();
    output();

    return 0;
}
```

when running my code , if the input have * at the first as follows :

```
4 4
*...
....
.*..
....
```

the output is :
[important to see it .. click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUvY9.jpg)
note: i tried to print the value of the symbol that appeard in the picture and it is 11 in ascii code which is vertical tab.

and , another problem if the * is at the last as follows :

```
4 4
...*
....
....
...*

000*
0000
0000
000*
```

but my code works well when the * is at the middle as follows :

```
4 4
....
..*.
.*..
....

0111
12*1
1*21
1110
```

so , what's the problem with my code ?

Comment: Please don't post images of text, and also please don't post links to images that can go stale. Copy-paste the text into the question.

Comment: There is a thing called 'debug' that allows you to trace your code. Sometimes trying on your own can help you understand it better and helps you avoid doing the same mistake.

Comment: Your problem may be related to the `scanf` with the character format `%c`: It also reads the new-line characters. As far as I can see, the only valid input for cells is a dot (free) or a star (mine). Enforce that condition and skip all other input. (Or skip all other white space and exit with an error otherwise.)

Comment: `for(int c = 0 ; c <= n ; c++)`  probably you need to use `c < n`

Comment: Another problem max arise when you count the adjacent mines on the border of the grid: You will likely step out of bounds by considering all adjacent cells unconditionally.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the symbol (vertical tab ) have no shape to be copied from the console .. sorry for that

Comment: @Valentin @M Oehm when scanning the elements the new line is registered in the last colon to make new line when printing so the condition must be c <= n

Comment: Okay, but that's a strange way to represent the minesweeper board. Consider separating the minesweeper grid proper from the representation. Still, you've got an error: After reading the dimensions, the next read char is a newline. You should also enforce that the input is valid and not take everything thze user types at face value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scanf("%d", ...);
```

leaves whitespace (the ENTER) in the input buffer. Then

```
scanf("%c", ...);
```

reads that whitespace into the variable.

You need to ignore the whitespace before (and during) reading the stars and dots.

Use

```
scanf(" %c", ...);
//    ^^^ ignore whitespace
```

*Note: the conversion specifier `"%d"` (and many others) already includes ignoring whitespace; the exceptions are `"%c"`, `"%["`, and [for different reasons] `"%n"`).*

Answer (score 3):

In this line you can go out of bounds:

```
        if(r >= 0 && c >= 0 && ms[r][c] != '*')
            ms[r][c] += 1 ;
```

You only test if *r* and *c* are not negative, but you should also test they are not too large.

The thing becomes more complicated because you have global variables *m* and *n* which are the dimensions of your array, but they are not available in the *calc* function, because there you have local variables with the same name.

So you better use different variable names. And then you should test that `r<m` and `c<n`,  as follows:

```
void calc(int p , int q){
    for(int r = p ; r <= (p+2) ; r++)
        for(int c = q ; c <= (q+2) ; c++)
            if(r >= 0 && c >= 0 && r < m && c < n && ms[r][c] != '*')
                ms[r][c] += 1 ;

}
```

Now the reason you saw an ASCII 11 is explained by the fact that ASCII 10 is the line feed character that marks the end of a row. Then when your code performs `ms[r][c] += 1` on it (because it goes too far), it becomes that funny character.

That you have that ASCII 10 in your array is explained by how you read the input (see @pmg's answer). If you would not have read those white space characters, you would still overrun, and probably touch data in a next row of data, which is not what you want to happen.